# Why I'm getting error I can't convert from float to int?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following line of code:

```
calcVector.y = (heightmapData[calcPosZ, calcPosX]) * terrainSize.y;
```

**Variables:**

`calcVector` is type `Vector3`

`heightmapData` is type `float[,]`

`calcPosZ`, `calcPosX` both type `float`

`terrainSize` is type `Vector3`

**the problem:**

The error I'm getting is on the part from the line:

```
heightmapData[calcPosZ, calcPosX]
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).

**What I tried:**

I tried to type (float) or (int) before the `heightmapData` I also tried to make `float.Parse(heightmapData.ToString())` but nothing worked.

**Why I'm getting error I can't convert from float to int?**

Comment: Indexes for arrays are integers not float. You need to change the type of _calcPosZ_ and _calcPosX_ to integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> calcPosZ and calcPosX both type float

This is **incorrect**. It has to be of type `int` as it represents the indices of the array `heightmapData`